# How to allow SSH only from local network via iptables

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

I would like to configure `iptables` to allow SSH on port 22 only from IPs from `192.168.*.*` and block from every other IP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19791/set-some-firewall-ports-to-only-accept-local-network-connections

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the required rules:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

The first rule allows connection through port 22 (ssh) on protocol tcp to everyone from the 192.168.0.0/16 networks.

The second rule allows connecting to ssh locally.

The third rule drops all other IP's/network coming through port 22.

Comment: Good stuff here! :)